# C# Method that executes a given Method

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I am trying to write the following: I would like to write a method "A" which takes as parameter another method "B" as well as an unknown number of parameters for this method B. (params object[] args). Now, inside method A i would like to make a call to B with the parameters args. B will now return an object which I would like A to return as well.

This all sounds a bit strange, therefore I will add some example code:

```
public object A(Func<object> B, params object[] args)
{
    object x = B.Method.Invoke(args);

    return x;
}
```

The problem is, that Func does not work like that. Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Regards,
Christian

Comment: Does your code work if you pass only some defined parameters, for example if you define Func to accept an integer and a string? I think your code is almost ok, not sure if Func could be defined to accept params...

Comment: Yes it does work if I define the parameters. However it does not accept something like Func<params object[], object> B.

Comment: Is b a fixed signature? Do you know what type B returns and takes? If not then you can't use any Func<..> signature. You'll have to use Delegate and dynamic invoke. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx

Comment: B is completely unknown. It will return something unknown and it takes an unknown number of parameters of unknown type. I'll have a look at that article, thanks!

Comment: dfowler is correct. That is the very solution that the framework uses, for example in the `ISynchronizeInvoke.Invoke` method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.invoke.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    Func<int> m1=()=>1;
    Console.WriteLine(A(m1));

    Func<int,int> m2=i=>i;
    Console.WriteLine(A(m2,55));
}

object A(Delegate B,params object[] args)
{

    return B.Method.Invoke(B.Target,args);
}
```

...goodbye type-safety

Comment: This does the job. Thank you! Well you're right, type-safety is gone but in my case there is no other way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

`Func<object>` is a delegate for a method that takes no arguments and returns `object`. If you change it to `Func<object,object>`, it will take an argument and return object:

```
public object A(Func<object, object> B, params object[] args)
{
    object x = B(args);

    return x;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that B may take more than 1 argument.

Comment: @Christian: since an array is also an `object` you can pass pretty much anything to a `Func<object, object>`. Then it is up to the called method to figure out what it actually got. So in your case with a `params object[] args`, you can pass `args` to a `Func<object, object>`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
public object A(Func<object[], object> B, params object[] args) 
{     
     object x = B(args);     
     return x; 
}
```

Comment: This would work if all my B's take an object array as parameter. I could use this, but it would be better if the B functions just stay as they are.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a code like this one:

```
public object A(Func<object[], object> B, params object[] args)
{
    object x = B(args);

    return x;
}
```

You're missing that the Func overload needs to accept your object array of arguments.

Anyway, if you need this method "A" to accept parameterless functions, you should create a paremeterless function parameter overload of "A".